# Could this C cast to avoid a signed/unsigned comparison make any sense?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, casting

I'm reviewing a C++ project and see effectively the following:

```
std::vector<SomeType> objects;

//then later
int size = (int)objects.size();
for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    process( objects[i] );
}
```

Here's what I see. `std::vector::size()` returns `size_t` that can be of some size not related to the size of `int`. Even if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(size_t)` `int` is signed and can't hold all possible values of `size_t`. So the code above could only process the lower part of a very long vector and contains a bug. The right way would be to use `size_t` for both the `size` variable and the loop index.

That said I'm curious of why the author might have written this?

My only guess is that first he omitted the `(int)` cast and the compiler emitted something like Visual C++ [C4018](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y92ktdf2(VS.71).aspx) warning:

```
warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
```

so the author though that the best way to avoid the compiler warning would be to simply cast the `size_t` to `int` thus making the compiler shut up.

Is there any other possible sane reason for that C cast?

Comment: Nitpick: `size()` returns an implementation-defined `vector::size_type`, not necessarily `size_t`.

Comment: Nitpick of the nitpick: default allocator does use `size_t` as `size_type`. Yes, you could write `vector<int>::size_type s = v.size();`, but when you change the allocator of `v`, you'll still be using the wrong `size_type` and need to find and change the usages (but again, typedefs can help).

Comment: As long as you typedef your vector type, using YourVectorTypedef::size_type should always give the right type back.

Comment: Nitpick of nitpick of nitpick: Only `std::string` uses `allocator::size_type` as its `size_type`. `std::vector` uses "an implementation defined unsigned integral type" instead.

Comment: @UncleBens ^^ (nitpick notifier)

Comment: @Johannes: I stand corrected. Still there seems to be lots of maintenance overhead (even if you use typedefs for all vector types, you'll still need to make sure that you use the right typedef at each place). Now, how does it factor in that `size_type` must be capable of representing any non-negative value of iterator's `difference_type`? :)

Comment: @UncleBens, Honestly, in my own codes i just use `unsigned`

Comment: @UncleBens: If you heard that from me, apologies. I spread that around here a bit but I was ill-informed. (I think because when I first checked, I looked at string, saw it used allocator::size_type, so I assumed containers did the same.)

Comment: @GMan: Actually, it appears so from drafts for C++98 when you look at the various headers synopsis. Perhaps it was changed later (oops, it's implementation defined in general requirements, but later it is said how it should be defined...)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that is probably the reason. Plus the fact that the vector would probably never be so long that it would risk truncating the size (the app. developer would know that).

And... maybe in some parts of the program he actually compared "size" with something else that was int-typed, so making size a "size_t" type would fix it in one place, but break it somewhere else.

Answer (score 9):

I would say that the overwhelming use of C casts in both C and C++ is simply to make the compiler shut up, with little or  no effort given to trying to understand what it is telling you. Sad, but true.

Comment: A lot of the errors are trivial, meaningless in context, or unreadable. Makes sense a lot of people's reaction will be 'just shut up'.

Comment: @Jay That isn't true. Most errors are meaningful, and applying a cast is almost always the wrong way of dealing with them. My own motto is - "if it needs a cast, it's wrong".

Answer (score 4):

The obvious answer would be to use:

```
size_t size = objects.size();
for( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    process( objects[i] );
}
```

or to be pedantically correct:

```
typedef std::vector<SomeType>::size_type s_t;
s_t size = objects.size();
for (s_t i=0; i<size; ++i)
    process(objects[i]);
```

OTOH, unless you're sure you need to write the loop yourself, you're generally better off using an algorithm:

```
std::foreach(objects.begin(), objects.end(), process);
```

Comment: In the first version you again cast to int.

Comment: @Sharptooth:Oops -- I copied his code and meant to fix it, but missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score -4):

```
unsigned int size = (int)objects.size();
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
    process( objects[i] );
}
```

Comment: What? Why not use `size_t` directly? Why still cast to `int`?

Comment: What? This is even worse. The expected type for the size variable is size_t, what's the point of going to unsigned int?

Comment: size_t could be bigger than unsigned int